# C Program: Adding a series using recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I am new to recursion so I am trying to write a simple program that adds to the nth number of the series 1/n. So if the user enters n = 4, the program will add 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4. My program keeps outputting that the sum of the series is 0. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong? I'd appreciate the help. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double sum(double n);

int main() {
    double n;
    double total;
    printf("Enter a positive integer greater than 0: ");
    scanf("%lf", &n);
    total = sum(n);
    printf("Sum: %lf", total);

    return 0;
}

double sum(double n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return ((1 / n) + sum(n - 1));
}
```

Comment: `(1 / n)` --> `(1.0 / n)`... `double sum(int n) {`

Comment: @Bluepixy's solution should work. I'd also like to point out that doubles and equality don't mix well! `if (n == 1)` could fail due to floating point error. You're much better off using an inequality. If `n` is an `int` (as in @Bluepixy's solution) then this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the definition of this function:

```
double sum(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return ((1 / n) + sum(n - 1));
}
```

`n` is `int` so `1/n` will be always evaluated as `int` since both 1 and `n` are integers. Thus `1/n` is always 0 for each n>1.

The solution would be to define `n` as `double` :

```
double sum(double n) {
    if (n <= 1.0)
        return 1.0;
    else
        return ((1.0 / n) + sum(n - 1.0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your base case. `sum(1)` should return 1.

Also, an int divided by an int returns an int. Use a floating point number in your division.

Comment: Oh yes I didn't realize I was using int n instead of double n. Thank you!

Comment: You edited your post to fix the first error. That's not the greatest way to create a knowledge base of helpful questions and answers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
double sum(double n) {
if (n == 1)
    return 1.0;
else
    return ((1.0 / n) + sum(n - 1));
}
```

1/n will always return 0 since 'n' acts as an integer value and not a float value even though the datatype is double as the value assigned to it is of type integer.